# ScrollView with GridLayout doesn't start at top

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview, android-gridview

Even in design view it starts somewhere in the middle and I can't scroll up, I can only scroll down. Similiarly when I run the app it shows the content somewhere in the middle and I can only scroll down, seems like the highest point is where I start. I don't know if it's a problem with margins or something else

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="16"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/myFrame">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/my_img1"
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="105dp"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_img"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/descTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="34dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:text="@string/text_1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </FrameLayout>
    .
    .
    .
```

Frame layouts repeat 32 times.

Comment: a horizontal grid layout with column count 2 in a vertical scrollview?? Also `FrameLayout` has no orientation just fyi

Comment: Is there a problem with horizontal grid layout?

Comment: if you want horizontal scrolling use a horizontal scroll view, if you have a scrollview, the first child of scrollview needs to be a layout that is expanding vertically like a vertical linear layout,

Comment: I changed the orientation of grid layout (which is a child of ScrollView) from horizontal to vertical, but it only changed the arrangment of items and it still doesn't start at the top but in the middle. I could scroll vertically when the child was horizontal too.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by removing android:layout_gravity="center" from GridLayout.